# Loading and saving scripts in a new environment

Tags: r, package

I am a newbie to package development in R. I learnt that there are differences between code in scripts and packages. When we use `source()` to load script each line of code is executed. But in case of packages codes are executed when they are built and results are saved. Next time when we load the package using `library()` or `require()` the cached results are available to us.

I created a script `time.R`. Script contains a single instruction as shown:

```
> ctime <- Sys.time()
```

My aim is to load and save the script in a new environment. Later on load it to verify that the time stored in `ctime` is not current time but actually the time when it was loaded.

```
> env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
> source('ctime.R',local = env)
  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "<-"
```

May be the error is because of using a new environment. Please help how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend reading [this beautiful article](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) to understand better what are `environment`s in R and how `R` finds functions and objects.

The problem in your case comes from the fact that you created your `env` to be "child" of `emptyenv`, i.e. the root of the environments' tree. When you evaluate an expression in such environment, R can just search functions in it or in its parent (which is empty). So, no function is actually found. You can try:

```
env <- new.env()
source("time.R",local=env)
```

and everything works. In the above case, the new environment is child of the environment in which the creation has been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support basic R functions in your sourced R file while minimizing side-effects due to environment "chaining" you can use the base environment as the parent of your environment:

```
# The "package:base" is R's base package and always required
# > search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
# [8] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"   

env <- new.env(baseenv())
source('ctime.R',local = env)

# Now it works without an error:
env$ctime
# [1] "2017-11-03 19:48:20 CET"
```